# how to display and map the first id of an state or const data array objects?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, object

I have a state like this:

```
 this.state={
        users:[
            {id:'1' , name:'jack' , familyname:'carry'},
            {id:'2' , name:'ben' , familyname:'rosvelt'},
            {id:'3' , name:'rans' , familyname:'mitoshy'},
        ]
    }
```

But I want to display the id of 1, or for example the id of 2  of the objects  actually one array to display, not display all of the array.

The mapping function that I wrote is like this below:

```
{this.state.users.map((item, i) => (
<li key={i.id}>{item.name}</li>
))}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to simply [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) the array, or only display items that match one or more ids?

Comment: no i want to display only just one user with a specific id for example .item [0].username

Answer (score 1):

You're using inconsistent arguments in your `map` function. You're trying to access `i.id`, which is the `id` property of an integer (the index). You don't need `i`, just use `item` like so:

```
{this.state.users.map(item => (
    <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
))}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a function that accepts the id you want to display as a parameter
then find the array to see which of the objects id is equal to the id e.g

```
display (id) {
  this.state.users.find(user) {
    if(user.id === 1) {
      return <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>
    }
  }
}
```